# Implementing pause in timer using html js

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to implement a timer using html and js. I am using `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` for the same. Until now I have been able to do with starting and stopping the timer. The 'pause button' also does pause the timer but when resuming it again takes the time mentioned in the textbox rather than the current time value.

I guess using the value displayed in the <span> will do the work but I have not been able to find how to make it work..

Below is the code on which I am currently working

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="number" id="tb1"></br></br>
    <span id="mins">0 </span>
    <span>:</span>
    <span id="secs">0 </span></br></br>
    <button id="start" onclick="javascript:onStart()">start</button>
    <button id="pause" onclick="javascript:onPause()">pause</button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="javascript:onStop()">stop</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

.js

```
var mintb;
var mins;
var secs=0;
var inter;

function onStart(){
  mintb = document.getElementById("tb1").value;
  mins=parseInt(mintb);
  document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = mins;
  inter = setInterval(timer,1000);
}

function onPause(){
  clearInterval(inter);
  console.log(mins);
  console.log(secs);
  
}

function onStop(){
  clearInterval(inter);
   mins=0;
   secs=0;
   document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = mins;
   document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = secs;
   
}

function timer(){
    document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = mins;
    document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = secs;
    secs = secs-1;
    if(secs<0){
    secs=59;
    mins=mins-1;
    console.log(mins);
    }
  
    if(mins<0){
      clearInterval(inter);
      document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = 00;
      document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML = 00;
    }
}
```

Edit: tmins was written by mistake in the last if, it is actually mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was correct

```
html 

<button id="resume" onclick="javascript:onResume()">Resume</button>

Js 

function onResume(){
     inter = setInterval(timer , 1000);
}
```

Without changing markup

```
function onPause() {
  clearInterval(inter);
  let button = document.querySelector('#pause')
  button.innerText = "Resume";
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'onResume()');
}
function onResume() {
  let button = document.querySelector('#pause')
  button.innerText = "Pause";
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'onPause()');
  inter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
```

Comment: So for this I have to add another button right? I was trying to do 'pause' on start itself (once paused if you click start it resumes the timer)

Comment: You can resuse  the pause button itself  to use resume function...  When pause function runs you can change the innerText of the pause button and use setAttritube method to change onclick  event's value from onPause to onResume ! ....

Comment: Check my answer again I updated it  ... the same I was talking about !

Comment: Oh, this solved a lot of queries. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome :-).  , Also by using same logic u can hide start when timer starts and replace bit with stop and vice versa

Comment: @Rishi N it's been a while now ! Please mark this question solved if your problems were solved

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval` clears the interval and resets the timer to 0.

You can refer this if you want to implement play and pause functionality - https://gist.github.com/ncou/3a0a1f89c8e22416d0d607f621a948a9